Every not established user can see vote counts
What's the use of the established user privilege

They may view the vote counts on posts

if anybody can acces the timeline of a post?

I'll find the reference later but as Jeff said,  basically,  "we needed a privilege for 1000 rep"

Well .. it is still easier ... :)

I'm with @StevenJeuris on the convenience idea, but maybe this is actually a bug. It might be worth looking around the main meta for discussion.

Seems the URL of any given question can be modified to produce a timeline: replace questions with posts and the title with timeline, and voila. I propose you change your username to Dr. Hax! :)

From Show Total Votes (or Up/Down Votes):

The total vote count (score) is denormalized, but the individual up/down vote counts are not.
So to display it on every post would incur 2 vote table queries * number of visible questions / answers. Our DB is fast, but the vote table is pretty massive, and not doing a query is always faster than doing it.

It's not so much that it's being "hidden" for some reason, it's just a practical performance concern.
